Бесконечная загрузка подключения Telethon Client
попала мне на руки странная сессия Telethon (.session), при попытке выполнить connect бесконечно грузится. Также добавлю сюда логирование от Telethon
Код:
import asyncio
import logging

from telethon import TelegramClient

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

async def main():
    client = TelegramClient(
        session='session_name',
        api_id=2040,
        api_hash='b18441a1ff607e10a989891a5462e627',
    )
    await client.connect()
    print(await client.get_me())
    await client.disconnect()

asyncio.run(main())

Логи
DEBUG:asyncio:Using proactor: IocpProactor
INFO:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Connecting to 149.154.167.40:443/TcpFull...
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Connection attempt 1...
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Connection success!
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Starting send loop
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Starting receive loop
INFO:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Connection to 149.154.167.40:443/TcpFull complete!
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Waiting for messages to send...
DEBUG:telethon.extensions.messagepacker:Assigned msg_id = 7418190276776993808 to InvokeWithLayerRequest (2393d0fe840)
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Encrypting 1 message(s) in 92 bytes for sending
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Encrypted messages put in a queue to be sent
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Waiting for messages to send...
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Receiving items from the network...

После чего бесконечная загрузка
